# CodeLite - unable to handle compilation, expected exactly one compiler job in ''

Tags: c++, codelite

I'm just starting out in C++, writing my first few programs in CodeLite. I keep getting this red arrow & warning message (shown below). I managed to fix it so that my code runs and works fine (had to open some of my files as an administrator?), but the message won't go away - would like to know if anyone else has had this issue and if you managed to fix it! (and how, please & thankyou)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select 'Plugins'->'Language Server'->'Settings' and uncheck the box that says 'Display Diagnostics' at the bottom of the page then click OK ( Drag down Setting Dialog to See it ). That should take care of those red arrows.

source:
https://www.udemy.com/course/beginning-c-plus-plus-programming/learn/lecture/18801890#questions/15870611